# How can I make such binary tree in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

[image: I need to make a binary tree]

How can I see such tree in my document?
I've got margins

```
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{top=25mm} 
\geometry{bottom=35mm} 
\geometry{left=35mm} 
\geometry{right=20mm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You've already tagged this question with {tikz-pgf}. What specifically do you have problem with? What have your tried so far? In its current form this question seems like a duplicate of various tree questions on this ite, e.g. [Unbalanced binary tree with forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171074/unbalanced-binary-tree-with-forest).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! With `forest`, which is based on Ti*k*Z, this is straightforward. You need to replace `X,Y,Z` by your numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={parent anchor=south}
 [{$(1,1,1)$}
  [{$(2,1,1)$}
   [{$(2,5,1)$}
    [{$(13,1,5)$}
     [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      ]
      [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      ]
     ]
     [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      ]
      [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      ]
     ]
    ]
    [{$(2,5,29)$}
     [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      ]
      [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      ]
     ]
     [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      ]
      [{$(X,Y,Z)$}
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since all the nodes are math, you might as well add `math content` as an option and ditch all the `$`.

Comment: How I can change the size, cause I've such margins 
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{top=25mm}
 \geometry{bottom=35mm}
 \geometry{left=35mm}
 \geometry{right=20mm}

Comment: @RuslanNevretdinov The current tree fits in such a document, but it won't fir if one adds all the numbers you have. Then the options include making the font smaller, decreasing the distances between siblings or using something like `adjustbox` to make the tree fit.